# integrating react native into existing android app

Tags: android, react-native

So I have a pretty robust android application and I want to add some code from a react-native only application in one activity. I've gone through the docs on the site and it turned out to be a lot more complicated to integrate a react-native app into an existing android native app. Among the may errors, this is the one I'm current stuck on, does anyone know where this comes from?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage$1
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.getNativeModules(CoreModulesPackage.java:96)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.LazyReactPackage.createNativeModules(LazyReactPackage.java:71)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:97)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:950)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:880)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:104)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:218)
                                                                                                                     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:197)
                                                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It's currently fetching the bundle and it gets to 100 percent but then the activity crashes with the error output above about CoreModulesPackages.

It's been pretty frustrating trying to get this thing up and running, there seems to be a bunch of errors from many sides, I had to import react native manually through an aar since the version on maven is archaic(0.20), download okhttp web socket support, FLog and .so loader stuff. Among also having to exclude architecture specific code. If anyone knows of an easier way to integrate a RN app into an existing codebase, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm coming from the native side trying to understand this thing. I set up npm, bundle up the js before staring the server and then run my app. After which i forward to the proper 8081 port. If I'm doing the sequence of steps wrong then someone please correct me. It's been 3 days. Halp.

Comment: a bit late... anyways can you attach the build.gradle file for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same error in my react native app on Android 5.x devices -- no issues on 6 or 7.

The issue ceased to occur after I removed Fabric.io Crashlytics as a dependency from my app.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I need those in my app. :/

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. 
Probles has been solved by properly configuration of [multidex for old android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l)
In my case I forgot to inherit my application class from `MultiDexApplication`